# django model relationship to two other models

Tags: python, django

I have two models in a django app, Doctor and the Django Built in User model. Each one can have many registered phone numbers and addresses. i decided to create an addressbook app to store addresses and phone numbers.

**models.py in addressbook app**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.db import models
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db.models import permalink
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from doctors.models import Doctor
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class AddressPhoneType(models.Model):
    type_name = models.CharField(_('Type'), max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Address / Phone Type')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Address / Phone Type')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.type_name


class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(_('City'), max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('City')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Cities')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.city


class Address(models.Model):
    """Address model."""
    body = models.TextField(_('Address'))
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)

    #content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name="content_type_address")
    #object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    #content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True)
    address_type = models.ForeignKey(AddressPhoneType)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Address')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Addresses')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.body


class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="""Phone number must be entered in the format: 
        '+999999999' or '999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.""")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], blank=True, max_length=15)
    description = models.CharField(_('Description'), max_length=100)
    phone_type = models.ForeignKey(AddressPhoneType)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Phone Number')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Phone Number')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.phone_number, self.description)
```

if you look under class Address, there is two foreign keys, one to a user and the other one to doctor, so each address entry can be associated with either one (same mechanics apply for phones). the problem is that when i go to the admin page and i add a doctor (I have the address model set to be shown inine in admin.py in doctors app), i see a user drop down to select a user for that added address which does not seem correct.[image]

I tried to use ContentType and GenericForeignKeys but i dont think they are the solution here....Any suggestions ?

Comment: I see this - `user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True)`

Comment: Is a doctor always a user? How is a doctor different from a user

Comment: @Sayse doctor and user are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have created an `AddressInline` inside the `DoctorAdmin`, if thats the case you can just exclude the user from the `inline`.

```
from django.contrib import admin

class AddressInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Address
    exclude = ('user',)

class DoctorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        AddressInline,
    ]
```

Comment: that is exactly what i needed, do you think the approach is the way to go. If i want those two models to have multiple addresses and phone numbers ?

Comment: I guess its fine, since one address can belong to only one user or doctor GFK is also an option, then you can use `GenericTabularInline` (check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline). And the `AddressPhoneType` class seems to me like over-engineering not sure whats the purpose of this field/model, but couldn't it  be just a ChoiceField instead of FK?

Comment: i wanted the application admin user to go the admin page and add addressphonetype [home, cell, clinic, office] etc